# Facebook API using Python. How to print out comments from ALL post?

Tags: python, facebook, api, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook API. Currently, I am trying to print out ALL the comments that have been posted for this facebook page called 'leehsienloong'. However, I could only print out a total of 700+ comments. I'm sure there are more than 700+ comments in total.

I find out that the problem is, I did not request to go to another page to print out the comments. I read about paging Facebook API, but I still do not understand how to do the code for paging.

Is there anyone out there who will be able to help/assist me? I really need help. Thank you.

Here is my code, without paging:

```
import facebook    #sudo pip install facebook-sdk
import itertools
import json
import re
import requests

access_token = "XXX"
user = 'leehsienloong'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
profile = graph.get_object(user)
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts')

Jstr = json.dumps(posts)
JDict = json.loads(Jstr)

count = 0
for i in JDict['data']:
    allID = i['id']
    try:
        allComments = i['comments']

        for a in allComments['data']:  
            count += 1
            print a['message']


    except (UnicodeEncodeError):
        pass


print count
```

Comment: You could check to see how many times you pass the UnicodeEncodeError with a secondary counter.

Anyone with a foreign name or with a comment using any non-ASCII text would like appear there. Just add a second counter and see if anything triggers the except statements.

Comment: In your code `posts` is already `dict` so no need to use `json.dumps` and `json.loads`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `limit` parameter to increase the number of comments to be fetched. The default is 25. You can increase it like this:

```
posts = graph.get_connections(profile['id'], 'posts', limit=100)
```

But more convenient way would be get the `previous` and `next` pages from `paging` and do multiple requests.

Comment: An example would be nice. Like what is the parameter to be used with the command. I tried     `next=`, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

to get all the comments of a post the logic should be something like

```
comments = [] 
for post in posts["data"]:
    first_comments = graph.get_connections(id=post["id"], connection_name="comments")
    comments.extend(first_comments["data"])
    while True:
        try:
            next_comments =  requests.get(post_comments["paging"]["next"]).json()
            comments.extend(next_comments["data"])
        except KeyError:
            break
```